# .usage taking up too much space?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 enterprise application. I noticed that recently my .usage files have been taking up a very large amount of space (over 50 GB at times). I know that I can made the "Maximum log file size" but it seems to just create more for the same day.

Is there any way to limit how many days the usage files take up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .usage files are part of the SharePoint 2010 Usage and Health Service and they contain information about the usage on the farm. The amount of information that is collected depends on the Usage Data Collection Event Selection.

The .usage files should be deleted after they have been processed and imported into your SharePoint Usage database. The job responsible for processing and deleting the logs is called "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import". There should typically be no more than 6 .usage files at any given time.

There is a common problem on Microsoft SharePoint 2010 that prevents .usage files from being deleted. It was created in a specific patch then later resolved in the December 2013 Cumulative Update for SharePoint 2010. There is a Microsoft Knowledge Base article that describes the behavior and solution located at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2916922

**EDIT**

Patches must be installed on every server in the farm with SharePoint installed on it. As these updates are cumulative, they include all previous fixes, so you may want to install the latest cumulative update for your environment.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn789211(v=office.14)

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to run this on every server on the farm (APP and WFE)?